# How to Eval with imported Module in ES6 and Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I use Webpack as a package manager and ES6. Looks like an imported module is not correctly evaluated with eval.
How to eval a string using the imported Module ?

Code:

In a global scope:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var tableDefinition = '{ value: "myvalue", myfunction: (v) => { return DateFormat.format(v) }}'; 
 </script>
```

---

In my module:

```
import DateFormat from "~modules/DateFormat"; // a module helper written by me

class GeneriClass {
    constructor() {
        DateFormat.init();
        let columns = eval(tableDefinition); // this code retrieves 'DateFormat' not defined
    }
}
```

The error on eval is: "'DateFormat' not defined!"

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Also,  make sure the import path of your module is correct (remember a `./` before the path is necessary if you're not importing from `node-modules`)

Comment: yes the path of the imported module is correct. if i use DateTime module outside eval it works. I added the error I'm getting in the comment (eval line)